# Stretch horizontal checkbox width to 100% with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I'm trying to make three horizontal checkboxes stretch to take up 100% of the width of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Primary Codes</h1><br>
      </div><!-- /header -->

      <div data-role="content"> 
        <h1 id="result">Code: <span id="prefix"></span><span id="suffix"></span></h1>
        <form>
          <div class="custom">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2a" id="phone">
              <label for="phone">Phone</label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2b" id="internet">
              <label for="internet">Internet</label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2c" id="video">
              <label for="video">Video</label>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup2">
            <legend></legend>
            <input type="radio" name="jobtype" id="1" value="1">
            <label for="1">New Aerial</label>
            <input type="radio" name="jobtype" id="2" value="2">
            <label for="2">New Underground</label>
            <input type="radio" name="jobtype" id="3" value="3">
            <label for="3">MDU/Apartment</label>    
            <input type="radio" name="jobtype" id="4" value="4">
            <label for="4">Reconnect</label>
          </fieldset>
        </form>

      </div><!-- /content -->

    </div><!-- /page -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/primary.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Inspecting this page in Brackets, it looks like the "fieldset" selector already has a width of 100%.

I've tried changing the widths for both "label" and "input" elements, but to no avail.

Note: I've seen similar discussions suggest using a navbar element, but because of the way my app works, this isn't really an option. It has to be the horizontal checkboxes.

Comment: you want each checkbox to stretch to 100%? in that case it will become a vertical one. Or, should each take up 33.33% ?

Comment: it is working already ! http://fiddle.jshell.net/yrzun2qr/ , post a screenshot of what you re trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a class to your `fieldset` letting you target things specifically within it, like this:

```
<fieldset class="fullwidth" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2a" id="phone">
  <label for="phone">Phone</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2b" id="internet">
  <label for="internet">Internet</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2c" id="video">
  <label for="video">Video</label>
</fieldset>
```

...then this pair of rules seems to work:

```
.fullwidth .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-checkbox {
    width: 100%;
}
.fullwidth .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-checkbox label {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/kiqaf)

Comment: Tried this one, and for some reason it made the horizontal checkboxes stack vertically, but you were on the right track. I just changed your CSS so that instead of .ui-checkbox label, the second CSS rule selected .fullwidth .ui-controlgroup-controls, and that did it!

Comment: One other thing I did was change the value of the first css selector to 33.333%. Those two things worked perfectly, so thank you!

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what you wanted, but I'm glad I helped you get there. :-)